# Load data from Azure Data Lake Store into SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-data-lake

I'm getting the following error when tried to create table from external table,

ERROR:

> OPEN failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.). [814e153e-58d5-4358-9b81-9e061154d1e4] failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.). [814e153e-58d5-4358-9b81-9e061154d1e4][2017-06-29T23:29:02.5068343-07:00].

Used Following example,

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimProduct]
 WITH (DISTRIBUTION = HASH([ProductKey]  ) )
 AS
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DimProduct_external]
 OPTION (LABEL = 'CTAS : Load [dbo].[DimProduct]');
```

What I have to do in order to overcome this?

Comment: Well, did you make sure that your user is `authorized to perform the requested operation`? On another thought, is it possible to just call the `SELECT` on its own?

Comment: Yes my user is authorized user and in fact he is the admin for the subscription.

Comment: I dont know about SELECT statement in external tables because this is the sample given in the msdn site.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-data-lake-store

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Lake Store permissions are quite picky. Just because you are a subscription admin doesn't mean you will have read/write/execute access on files and folders within the data lake, which has a POSIX-like permission system.

In the Azure Portal, try going to the data lake and giving your admin user read/write/execute permissions on the root folder, making sure to select the options that include children and give default access.